# conditionally remove part of a string after a character in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of names that looks like this:

```
names <- c("Verticordia (Cha)", "Whiteodendron\n(Loph)", "Platysace", 
"Xanthostemon\n(Xan)", "Quercus (incl.\nCyclobalanopsis)\n(Fag)"
)
[1] "Verticordia (Cha)"                       "Whiteodendron\n(Loph)"                   "Platysace"                               "Xanthostemon\n(Xan)"                    
[5] "Quercus (incl.\nCyclobalanopsis)\n(Fag)"
```

I would like to conditionally remove all characters thatcome after a space or a `\`, including the space or the `\`. I have been able to remove the `\` or the space using:

```
gsub("\n*","",names)
gsub(" *","",names)
```

However, I am having trouble getting the code to remove all following characters as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gsub("\n.*","",names)
gsub(" .*","",names)
```

You want the asterisk quantifier to apply to the dot (which is a wildcard matching all characters).  Your version applied the quantifer to the newline or space character, so you were removing only strings of consecutive newlines or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Or all in 1 regex:

```
names.reduced <- gsub('[ \\\n].*', '', names)

[1] "Verticordia"   "Whiteodendron" "Platysace"     "Xanthostemon"  "Quercus"
```

Comment: thanks so much. its amazing how opaque regex is to me. Looking at this code there is nothing intuitive about it, ha.

Comment: Regular expressions are amazing, but they're really a programming language unto themselves. Seconds to start using, years to master.